# GHC.Generics example doesn't work

Tags: haskell, generics

I'm trying to get the example implementation of a generic binary encoding class described in [GHC.Generics](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/GHC-Generics.html) to work, but when I try to compile it the following code I get an error.

```
import GHC.Generics

class Encode' f where
  encode' :: f p -> [Bool]

instance Encode' V1 where
  encode' x = undefined

instance Encode' U1 where
  encode' U1 = []

instance (Encode' f, Encode' g) => Encode' (f :+: g) where
  encode' (L1 x) = False : encode' x
  encode' (R1 x) = True  : encode' x

instance (Encode' f, Encode' g) => Encode' (f :*: g) where
  encode' (x :*: y) = encode' x ++ encode' y

instance (Encode c) => Encode' (K1 i c) where
  encode' (K1 x) = encode x

instance (Encode' f) => Encode' (M1 i t f) where
  encode' (M1 x) = encode' x

class Encode a where
  encode :: a -> [Bool]
  default encode :: (Generic a) => a -> [Bool]
  encode x = encode' (from x)
```

GHC complains with:

```
Could not deduce (Encode' (Rep a)) arising from a use of ‘encode'’
from the context (Encode a)
  bound by the class declaration for ‘Encode’
  ...
or from (Generic a)
  bound by the type signature for encode :: Generic a => a -> [Bool]
  ...
In the expression: encode' (from x)
In an equation for ‘encode’: encode x = encode' (from x)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Change the default type signature to `default encode :: (Generic a, Encode' (Rep a)) => a -> [Bool]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not everything that is `Generic` can be encoded by `encode'`. Only those things that are both `Generic` and have a representation, `Rep a` that has an `Encode'` instance can be encoded by the generic `encode'`. The compiler doesn't know (and can't know) that there isn't something `Generic` whose `Rep` isn't covered by an `Encode'` instance. An author of a `Generic` instance could use a type for their `Rep` that doesn't even exist yet.

You need to add the requested `Encode' (Rep a)` constraint to the context for the `default encode`.

```
default encode :: (Generic a, Encode' (Rep a)) => a -> [Bool]
```

Comment: Even when the compiler *does* know something, Haskell insists that the constraints (which may incur a run-time bookkeeping cost) be explicit.